# JSF PrimeFaces multiple datatable on single view sorting NPE focus problem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've got a problem with PrimeFaces dataTables.

My case:
4 datatables on one view. I'm able only to sort last one. I think it's some kind of focus on it. Clicking column header on another tables leads to following NPE:

```
05-Feb-2019 11:55:03.542 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.logException null
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumnInGroup(DataTable.java:962)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumn(DataTable.java:953)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.decode(SortFeature.java:86)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:478)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:287)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:775)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:213)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:827)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:345)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1044)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1044)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1044)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191).......
```

Code for each view is something like following - they all are in separate forms

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="row" paginator="true" id="dataList#{formId}"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="#{bean.tablePaginatorSizes}" rows="#{bean.tableDefaultPaginatorSize}"
                 emptyMessage="#{lang.label_no_records_found}"
                 selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{row.id}" widgetVar="packListTab">
   <p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{row.id.packageId}" filterBy="#{row.idStr}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                      width="150">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.idStr}"/>
            </p:column> 
</p:datatable>
```

PF version 6.0

Edit:

I upgraded PF to 6.2, NPE with different stacktrace showed up

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.decode(SortFeature.java:80)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:478)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:296)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:775)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:213)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:850)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:345)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1044)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1044)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
```

[image: debug result]

It's weird, client is from another form (last one) than the column.

Comment: I think I have run into this before.  Are all 4 of your datatables using var="row"?  If so change all 4 of them to be unique var="row1" var="row2" or something unique.  Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: And _"Code for each view is something like following"_ is really bad when posting code....

Comment: What's the primefaces version number ... about ...? (Sarcasm in here, don't feel offenden plz.)

Comment: @Melloware Your solution seemed to be reasonable, but still no luck.

Comment: @Kukeltje I meant that they all have similar code, same type and structure. Only differing in data.

Comment: @Selaron I edited question - it's PrimeFaces 6.0. Seems to be a PF bug for me.

Comment: But if it is not posted we can not check if an error was made. Hence, **always** create a [mcve]. And if you think it is a bug, try (just in your [mcve]) with a newer version, the latest preferably

Comment: Not sure if `sortBy="#{row.id.packageId}" ` is possible this way. Maybe you have to define a custom sorting function. Your 2nd stack trace points out Primefaces is not able to find a column by `sortKey` posted thru parameter `clientId + "_sortKey"`.

Comment: @Selaron I doubt it, but tried anyway. Doesn't work. It seems that weird kind of focus is on last datatable (for which sorting works as a charm). Even when itry to sort another dataTable, blockUI appears on last dataTable for a moment before NPE. Tried to debug JS, but it seems to be ok there.

Comment: You have a strange ID assignment: `id="dataList#{formId}"` Did you `h:form prependId="false"`?

Comment: @Selaron It's like this because it's template ui:include'd 4 times. But that is not concerning issue (tried to paste same code 4 times). Could you take a look at question again? I edited it - there is wrong clientId - it's from f2, and sortingKey is from f0. I clicked on f0 one. In that case it's not surprising that PF isn't able to find that sortingKey.

Comment: Please provide a real [mcve]  as Kukeltje already asked for in order to enable someone to reproduce this. We'd do endless try&error else and reasonably soon be warned that comment area is not ment to be used as a chat.

Comment: New questions in new questions please.

Answer (score 1):

The NPE indeed seemes has been a bug in Primefaces [tracked by issue 2059](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2059) where a `null` check was missing on a nullable object reference. Upgrading to Primefaces 6.1 should fix this NPE.

Found this by inspecting the StackTrace in Eclipse `Java StackTrace console` with Primefaces 6.0 source code and compared that method implementation of `DataTable.findColumnInGroup(...)` with the one in Primefaces 6.1 source code. The latter one contains the `null` check:

```
public UIColumn findColumnInGroup(String clientId, ColumnGroup group) {
    if(group == null) {
        return null;
    }

    FacesContext context = this.getFacesContext();

    for(UIComponent row : group.getChildren()) {
    // ...
    }
}
```

[Blaming the change in source tree](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blame/7daa01603e2e9b90aa7803b6c6498650de61d7c6/src/main/java-templates/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableTemplate.java#L469) pointed me to the tracked issue mentioned above.

Comment: I updated question - upgrading to PF 6.2 seems to resolve that issue, but another one (similar) appears.

Comment: Now this is a good example of debugging and using the open source!